# What is timeout_id in GTK for?

Tags: gtk, pygobject

I'm reading through the official PyGObject tutorial, and I found this (unexplained) line in one of the examples:

```
self.timeout_id = None
```

(it was within an `__init__` function of a `Gtk.Window`-descendant class; the whole listing is [here](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/entry.html#example)).  I couldn't google it; what is it for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't see it being set and used further down in on_pulse_toggled ?

It is assigned the return value of GObject.timeout_add, which adds a function to be called at a later interval, possibly repeatedly (like in this case):

```
        self.timeout_id = GObject.timeout_add(100, self.do_pulse, None)
```

When you want this timeout not be called anymore, you have to remove it, and to do so, you need the id of the timeout you created:

```
        GObject.source_remove(self.timeout_id)
```

Comment: Thanks, stupid me!  (I didn't see it because I didn't read further down.)

Do I guess correctly that in general there's no `timeout_id` "property" in `Gtk.Window` class, and that in this case it is essentially (something like) a user-defined global variable?

Comment: No, it's not a global variable.  It's an instance variable, an object member.  gtk.Window does not have a timeout_id instance variable, but even if it did it would be overwritten in this subclass.

Comment: Thanks again. I know it's not a global var; I was trying to say that it plays a role of a one (in this short program there's only one `Gtk.Window` object).

Comment: To me it doesn't play the role of a global variable at all.  In fact, if this were my code, I would indicate the variable is private to the object, by prefixing it with an underscore.  Just because there's only one object of this class around in this application, doesn't make its instance variable play the role of a global variable.